# Ionic Android apk no access to internet

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an app for Android with Ionic/Cordova. The app works fine in the emulator and works fine in the Ionic view app. 
The app connects to an API in our internal network and everything works fine.

The problem is, when I build the cordova app to Android and install the apk, it doesn't connect to the internet. I can't seem to find what the problem is and why it is not connecting, even though it does work in the emulator and Ionic view.

Does anyone know what the problem would be and why it doesn't work?

Comment: check whether you have permission for accessing the internet in androidmanifets.xml. The permission will be like this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: This one already was added. Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems I had to install the Ionic whitelist plugin: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist

Now it is working! Thanks for your help guys

Comment: In my case, I needed to save white list plugin in config.xml `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save`

Answer (score 0):

This plugin saved my time:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```